# Acumatica - Import Scenario - Find customer using custom field

Tags: acumatica, erp

I'm building an import scenario so CSV's from an external system can be imported into Sales Orders.

The external system has a list of customers, with their own ids.
Acumatica also has a list of customers, and a custom field that stores the external systems customer id.

Is it possible to configure the import scenario to designate the customer by matching by this custom field?

i.e. Say on the Order Summary target object, rather than setting the Customer -> Customer ID, can I use Customer -> Ext. Customer ID

Comment: Is this question about programming?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a development question.

Comment: I assumed the answer would involve code since its probably not possible using standard functionality.